Deeplinking [APK build]
Deeplink works perfectly if I run the project via flutter run -d [device] , but when I install it via APK from flutter build apk, the deep link does not work anymore. I already added the keystore from C:\Users\username\ .android\debug.keystore. The domain where the assetlinks.json can be seen is configured properly also. Is there something I am missing here. Thank you in advance.

I figured it out, it turns out there is a different sha256 for release. I just run this command inside my android folder.
./gradlew signingReport

It basically prints the sha256 that are used by your packages both in debug and release mode.
